# End of css class variable

Tags: html, css

I have the following class, the last numbers are variable.

Is it possible to define only the begin like this but with some wildcard?

```
<style>
.cm-reload-ajax {border:1px solid #ff0000;}
</style>

class="cm-reload-ajax30151"
```

Answer, i did it with an id:

```
div[id^="add_to_cart_update_ajax"]{text-align:right;}
```

Comment: why do you need to have those numbers in the html ?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why not add one stable class, e.g. `class="cm-reload-ajax ajax12345"`?

Comment: they are generated by that script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are supporting newer CSS3 browsers, you need the following selector:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

Example:

```
div[class^="cm-reload-ajax"]
```

If you have HTML like:

```
<p class="cm-reload-ajax1212">The 1212 text...</p>
<p class="cm-reload-ajax2312">The 2312 text...</p>
<p class="cm-reload-ajax3412">The 3412 text...</p>
<p class="cm-reload-ajax4512">The 4512 text...</p>
```

Then you can style all these elements using the CSS:

```
p[class^="cm-reload-ajax"] {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 1.00em;
}
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EqFj7/